# Accessing hashmap field value as &mut inside struct impl

Tags: hashmap, rust, borrow-checker

given a simple struct like this:

```
struct Server {
  clients: HashMap<usize, Client>
}
```

what is the best way to access `Client` as a `&mut`? Consider the following code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Client {
  pub poked: bool
}

impl Client {
  pub fn poked(&self) -> bool {
    self.poked
  }

  pub fn set_poked(&mut self) {
    self.poked = true;
  }
}

struct Server {
  clients: HashMap<usize, Client>
}

impl Server {
  pub fn poke_client(&mut self, token: usize) {
    let client = self.clients.get_mut(&token).unwrap();
    self.poke(client);
  }

  fn poke(&self, c: &mut Client) {
    c.set_poked();
  }
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = Server { clients: HashMap::new() };
    s.clients.insert(1, Client { poked: false });

    s.poke_client(1);

    assert!(s.clients.get(&1).unwrap().poked() == true);
}
```

The only two options I see are to use `RefCell`/`Cell` inside Client, which makes things look really horrible:

```
pub struct Client {
    nickname: RefCell<Option<String>>,
    username: RefCell<Option<String>>,
    realname: RefCell<Option<String>>,
    hostname: RefCell<Option<String>>,
    out_socket: RefCell<Box<Write>>,
}
```

Or to wrap the `clients` in `RefCell`, which makes it impossible to have simple methods like this one for `Server`:

```
pub fn client_by_token(&self, token: usize) -> Option<&Client> {
    self.clients_tok.get(&token)
}
```

forcing me to use closures (e.g. `with_client_by_token(|c| ...)`).

Comment: The Rust style guide is 4-space indents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't reborrow `self` when it is already mutably borrowed:

```
<anon>:24:5: 24:9 error: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because `self.clients` is also borrowed as mutable
<anon>:24     self.poke(client);
              ^~~~
```

In your method:

```
pub fn poke_client(&mut self, token: usize) {
    let client = self.clients.get_mut(&token).unwrap();
    self.poke(client);
}
```

You borrow `self` mutably on the first line, and then try to borrow it again for the second line, when you call the method `poke`. The easiest solution is to just call `Client::set_poked` here:

```
pub fn poke_client(&mut self, token: usize) {
    let client = self.clients.get_mut(&token).unwrap();
    client.set_poked();
}
```

The other solution is to introduce a method that doesn't require `self`:

```
impl Server {
    pub fn poke_client(&mut self, token: usize) {
        let client = self.clients.get_mut(&token).unwrap();
        Server::poke(client);
    }

    fn poke(c: &mut Client) {
        c.set_poked();
    }
}
```

You can pass any other parts of `self` that are needed for `poke`. This may be a good time to introduce a new object that mediates between `Server` and `Client`.